# Border bottom with fixed size

Tags: html, css, border

What is the best way to add a small `border` at the bottom of a text?

The `border` has to be centered and maximum `20px`, but the text can be very long, even `200px.`

So it's like:

```
<h1>This text can be longer than the border</h1>
<style>
.h1 {border-bottom:8px solid #000;}
</style>
```

Should I add a `div` after my `h1` and set a maximum size for it?

Comment: Text will be one line or multiple lines? If multiple lines should border appear only after the last line?

Comment: should not be multiple lines, but it can happen in mobile view.... so better consider multiple lines. and yes, only after last line

Answer (score 7):

you can use pseudo element `::after` and use `left:50%` / `transform:translateX(-50%)` to align in the middle no matter the `width`

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  /* min-width:200px */
}
h1::after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>This text can be longer than the border</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using Linear Gradients for Background:**

Or you can also do this using `linear-gradient` background images. Advantage of using a gradient is that it doesn't require any extra pseudo-elements which can be used for other purposes. The border's thickness is based on the `background-size` in Y-axis and the width of the border is based on the size in X-axis. The `background-position` property is used to center the border.

The disadvantage is the relatively poor browser support for `linear-gradient` as compared to pseudo elements. Gradients are supported only in IE10+.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 4px; /* to give some gap between text and border */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, black);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 2px;
  background-position: 50% 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>This text can be longer than the border</h1><br>
<h1>Some text with lesser length</h1><br>
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

---

**Using a Pseudo-element:**

You can do this using a pseudo-element. By adding a pseudo-element with 20px `width`, positioning it absolutely we will be able to produce the required effect. The `left: 50%`, `translateX(-50%)` is used to position the pseudo-element at the center. The `height` of the pseudo-element determines border's thickness while the `background` determines the color of the border.

Advantage of this is the browser support as it should work in IE8+.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 4px; /* to give some gap between text and border */
}
h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>This text can be longer than the border</h1>
<br>
<h1>Some text with lesser length</h1>
<br>
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35650279/3880255) of [dippas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3448527/dippas), you can see when you use bigger widths, the border of the `after` elements is innacurate. You can prevent this by using `calc(50% - 100px);` instead of 50% whereas the `100px` are half the width of the `after` element.

```css
.bottom-border {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.bottom-border::after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<p class="bottom-border">
  Hi, i am a quite long text, might be 200px, probably more i guess, but nobody knows really.
</p>
```

Comment: Actually if you had used `translateX(-50%)` the `left: 50%` would have worked :) The reason is because we need to move the element by half its width in the X axis (to the left). I did the same mistake myself in the original version of my answer :D

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right! Thanks for the information, much appreciated! :)